# SQL Conversion Issue: Comparing selected part of VarChar and money

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that I cannot modify that I need to do a comparison between 2 columns on.

- The first column `TtlPrice` has a `money` datatype
- The second `AuthComments` has a `varchar(max)` datatype

We are typing a comment in the `AuthComments` column and at the end, adding a "$1.00" (or whatever price we are authorizing). I want to make sure that the `TtlPrice` isn't higher than the price in the `AuthComment` field.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
OrderNo | TtlPrice | AuthComment
--------+----------+----------------------
12345   | 51.74    | Auth by Sue- $62.84
```

Here is my current query:

```sql
SELECT
    OrderNo, 
    TtlPrice, 
    AuthComment 
FROM     
    tableA
WHERE
    (CAST(TtlPrice AS VarChar) > CAST(SUBSTRING(AuthComments,
                                                CHARINDEX('$', AuthComments) + 1,
                                                LEN(AuthComments) - CHARINDEX('$', AuthComments)) AS varchar))
```

The above, based on the data, should yield 0 results, because `TtlPrice` is less than the `AuthComment` price. But it is not, it is yielding 1 line result. I think it is not comparing the `varchar` properly, but trying to convert to any sort of numeric (int, money, etc) throws a conversion error. Suggestions?

Comment: You are comparing strings to strings, so you are going to get that `'10.00' < '9.00'`.

Comment: Converting 2 numbers to strings for comparison is fundamentally wrong. Instead of casting number to a string, work on casting the string to a number. '111' as a string will be less than '55' etc

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
with extracted_auth_comment_data AS (
  SELECT
    OrderNo, 
    TtlPrice, 
    AuthComment,
    TRY_CAST(value AS MONEY) AS auth_comment_value
  FROM     
    tableA
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(AuthComment, '$') 
  WHERE TRY_CAST(value AS MONEY) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT 
  OrderNo, 
  TtlPrice, 
  AuthComment
FROM extracted_auth_comment_data 
WHERE TtlPrice > auth_comment_value
```

The above query should return zero rows if the values in the AuthComment are always less than those in the TtlPrice.